# How to store a list of maps in ObjectBox box?

Tags: flutter, dart, objectbox, flutter-objectbox

I'm trying to store a list of Maps in the ObjectBox box, but since I'm new to ObjectBox I don't understand how to store custom data types.

**The data I'm trying to store (Structure looks like this)**

```
name: 'name',
total: 100,
refNo: 00,
listOfProds: [{Map1},{Map2},{Map3},...]//<-Problem
```

**I've tried**

```
@Entity()
class ABC{
  int id;
  String name;
  int total;
  int refNo;
  List<Map>? products;

  ABC({
  this.id=0,
  required this.name,
  required this.total,
  required this.refNo,
  //required this.products, <-This will throw an error since List is not supported
  });
}

//Adding into DB
void addIntoDB(){
  late ABC _abc;
  _abc = ABC(
   name: 'name',
   total: 100,
   refNo: 00,
   //How can I assign the 'list of maps here' or any other ways?
  );
  _store.box<ABC>().put(_abc);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Referring to the [Custom Types Documentation](https://docs.objectbox.io/advanced/custom-types), turns out that storing a list in a raw format is not possible. *(It's still in feature request)*

**So instead try converting that list to JSON format, which would result in a single string.**

```
String listInJson = json.encode(theList);
```

and now put that into box:

```
@Entity()
class ABC{
  int id;
  String name;
  int total;
  int refNo;
  String products;

  ABC({
  this.id=0,
  required this.name,
  required this.total,
  required this.refNo,
  required this.products,
  });
}

//Adding into DB
void addIntoDB(){
  late ABC _abc;
  _abc = ABC(
  name: 'name',
  total: 100,
  refNo: 00,
  products: listInJson,//<- That's how you do it.
  );
_store.box<ABC>().put(_abc);
}
```

and when retrieving, simply `json.decode(products)`.